# Closing a UserForm also closes my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've this macro in an UserForm to register accounting operations, after I finish the registration and I click the "x" button in the Userform my excel workbook close without asking me. I know this piece of code is the problem because my Userform do other things and these other things don't cause this problem.

```
Confirmar = MsgBox("¿Desea registrar la nueva operación contable?", vbYesNo)

If Confirmar = vbYes Then
   Next_LibroDiario = WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   If APP_RegistroContable.OptionButton_Débito = True Then
      WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 7) = APP_RegistroContable.Monto + 0
      APP_RegistroContable.Monto = ""

   ElseIf APP_RegistroContable.OptionButton_Crédito = True Then
      WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 8) = APP_RegistroContable.Monto + 0
      APP_RegistroContable.Monto = ""

   ElseIf APP_RegistroContable.OptionButton_Débito = False _
   And APP_RegistroContable.OptionButton_Crédito = False _
   Then
      MsgBox "Please select an accounting item"
      Exit Sub

   End If

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 2) = APP_RegistroContable.Ctas_Bancarias
   APP_RegistroContable.Ctas_Bancarias = ""

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 3) = CDate(APP_RegistroContable.Fecha)
   APP_RegistroContable.Fecha = ""

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 4) = APP_RegistroContable.Recibo_CF
   APP_RegistroContable.Recibo_CF = ""

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 5) = APP_RegistroContable.Nombre
   APP_RegistroContable.Nombre = ""

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 6) = APP_RegistroContable.Auxiliar + 0

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 9) = APP_RegistroContable.Clasificación
   APP_RegistroContable.Clasificación = ""

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Next_LibroDiario, 10) = APP_RegistroContable.Comentario
   APP_RegistroContable.Comentario = ""
```

' This part creates an ID for the accounting operation using the date registered and the number of 
' operations registered in that date

```
   Last_ID = WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

   Set Rang_Fecha = WShe_LibroDiario.Range("C8:C" & Last_ID)
   Set Rang_ID = WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Last_ID, 3)

   Inte_IDGenerator = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rang_Fecha, Rang_ID)

   WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Last_ID, 1).Value = WShe_LibroDiario.Cells(Last_ID, 3).Value & "-0" & _
   Inte_IDGenerator

   MsgBox "The accounting operation is now in the system"

End if
```

Comment: Run code step by step or add "Stop" lines, later check events e.g. UserForm_QueryClose and similar. The problem is probably outside code yo've just presented. And use With statement for "WShe_LibroDiario" because your code is difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for the "with" recommendation, my code looks more clean now, how do I check events e.g. UserForm_QueryClose?